# CSS with a PHP extension?

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to name my css file `mystyles.php`. All content within will still be css. I'd like to then include this into my `index.php` page without using the standard HTML `<link>` tag. Any direction would be appreciated very much.

Comment: header method? Try rewording your question and it might get easier to answer.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it inline, or how to make a php file that uses header to make it render as css. 

And if you are asking that, what are you asking?

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe to use php variables in the CSS file? Or to compute who sees what. That is at least what I use it for.

Answer (score 5):

Start your mystyle.php file with.

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Then echo out the elements.

Answer (score 4):

Include styles in your mystyle.php file that should look like this:

```
<?php

<style type="text/css">
  /* your styles here.......... */
</style>

?>
```

Now you can include that file using `include`:

```
include `mystyle.php`
```

In the end i wonder why don't you use the stylesheet link instead.